# C++ Debugging: trouble in both eclipse and command line

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, command-line

[SOLVED: SEE MY ANSWER BELOW]

Either I'm confused, or they really don't make this easy for beginners. I built some code that's not mine and should be tested and working, but it's not. Upon doing './execname' I get "Segmentation fault".

Eclipse debugging: setting up a debug configuration is strange because it sees no binaries in the project, though the binary is sitting right there in the project. So I have to hunt it down on the filesystem. I set my breakpoint in the corresponding cpp file, but upon debugging I get "No source available for "main() at 0x804a64e"".

Command line debugging: I did 'gdb execname', and it says it's reading symbols from the file I gave it (makes sense). Then I do 'break 273' and it says "No line 273 in file "../Common/InitShader.cpp""?? Why is it looking there?? It's not the file I gave gdb!

Code that gives the segmentation fault:

```
// rotating cube with two texture objects
// change textures with 1 and 2 keys

#include "Angel.h"

const int  NumTriangles = 12; // (6 faces)(2 triangles/face)
const int  NumVertices  = 3 * NumTriangles;
const int  TextureSize  = 64;

typedef Angel::vec4 point4;
typedef Angel::vec4 color4;

// Texture objects and storage for texture image
GLuint textures[2];

GLubyte image[TextureSize][TextureSize][3];
GLubyte image2[TextureSize][TextureSize][3];

// Vertex data arrays
point4  points[NumVertices];
color4  quad_colors[NumVertices];
vec2    tex_coords[NumVertices];

// Array of rotation angles (in degrees) for each coordinate axis
enum { Xaxis = 0, Yaxis = 1, Zaxis = 2, NumAxes = 3 };
int      Axis = Xaxis;
GLfloat  Theta[NumAxes] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
GLuint   theta;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int Index = 0;

void
quad( int a, int b, int c, int d )
{
    point4 vertices[8] = {
    point4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    point4(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
    };

    color4 colors[8] = {
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
    };

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[a];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 0.0, 0.0 );
Index++;

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[b];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 0.0, 1.0 );
Index++;

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[c];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 1.0, 1.0 );
Index++;

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[a];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 0.0, 0.0 );
Index++;

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[c];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 1.0, 1.0 );
Index++;

quad_colors[Index] = colors[a];
points[Index] = vertices[d];
tex_coords[Index] = vec2( 1.0, 0.0 );
Index++;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
colorcube()
 {
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
   quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init()
{
colorcube();

// Create a checkerboard pattern
for ( int i = 0; i < 64; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 64; j++ ) {
        GLubyte c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0)) * 255;
        image[i][j][0]  = c;
        image[i][j][1]  = c;
        image[i][j][2]  = c;
        image2[i][j][0] = c;
        image2[i][j][1] = 0;
        image2[i][j][2] = c;
    }
}

// Initialize texture objects
glGenTextures( 2, textures );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0] );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, TextureSize, TextureSize, 0,
      GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1] );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, TextureSize, TextureSize, 0,
      GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2 );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0] );

// Create a vertex array object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );

// Create and initialize a buffer object
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
      sizeof(points) + sizeof(quad_colors) + sizeof(tex_coords),
      NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

// Specify an offset to keep track of where we're placing data in our
//   vertex array buffer.  We'll use the same technique when we
//   associate the offsets with vertex attribute pointers.
GLintptr offset = 0;
glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sizeof(points), points );
offset += sizeof(points);

glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset,
         sizeof(quad_colors), quad_colors );
offset += sizeof(quad_colors);

glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sizeof(tex_coords), tex_coords );

// Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader71.glsl", "fshader71.glsl" );
glUseProgram( program );

// set up vertex arrays
offset = 0;
GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
           BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) );
offset += sizeof(points);

GLuint vColor = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vColor" ); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );
glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
           BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) );
offset += sizeof(quad_colors);

GLuint vTexCoord = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vTexCoord" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );
glVertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
           BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) );

// Set the value of the fragment shader texture sampler variable
//   ("texture") to the the appropriate texture unit. In this case,
//   zero, for GL_TEXTURE0 which was previously set by calling
//   glActiveTexture().
glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture"), 0 );

theta = glGetUniformLocation( program, "theta" );

glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUniform3fv( theta, 1, Theta );

    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if ( state == GLUT_DOWN ) {
    switch( button ) {
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:    Axis = Xaxis;  break;
       case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:  Axis = Yaxis;  break;
       case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:   Axis = Zaxis;  break;
}
}
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
idle( void )
{
Theta[Axis] += 0.01;

if ( Theta[Axis] > 360.0 ) {
Theta[Axis] -= 360.0;
}

glutPostRedisplay();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int mousex, int mousey )
{
switch( key ) {
case 033: // Escape Key
case 'q': case 'Q':
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    break;
case '1':
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0] );
    break;

case '2':
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1] );
    break;
}

glutPostRedisplay();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
glutInit( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );
glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
glutCreateWindow( "Color Cube" );

glewInit();

init();

glutDisplayFunc( display );
glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
glutMouseFunc( mouse );
glutIdleFunc( idle );

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it should be ./execname (without space), but i guess it was a writing mistake in the post..can you please post the code that gives segmentation?

Comment: When you add a breakpoint in GDB, you have to tell it which _source_ file to set the breakpoint in. If you don't know where is crashes, just `run` after starting GDB, and do whatever you need to do to make the program crash.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried specifying source and I get "No source file named example1.cpp". I tried relative and absolute paths, same thing. Why wouldn't it be seeing the file? Also, when I run in gdb, it instantly crashes giving: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()" does this tell us anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had done this already, but I think adding -g (debug option) into the makefile let gdb do what it needed. So now I know where the fault happens, but have no idea why, so this issue is moving to a question about openGL programming.

Comment: and now that gdb is working, doesn't it tell you the state of memory stack at the moment of the segmentation fault?
You should check which variables are present in that moment and understand the one that is faulting (accessing memory locations that it shouldn't)

Comment: Doing a backtrace gives: (gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0804a211 in init () at example1.cpp:147
#2  0x0804a6bc in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff3d4) at example1.cpp:283
This isn't very informative, but I found the line in Eclipse debugger: its a call to openGL method: glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao ); So is there yet more debug info I can extract?

Comment: is glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao) the correct way of calling this method?
cause &vao passes to the method the address where variable vao has been stored, maybe the method is expecting insted the value of vao, as in the method glBindVertexArray( vao );

Comment: I believe it's correct. Similar examples I have do it the same way, and they work.

Comment: It's really hard to help you do the debugging without code..I'm sorry, but the only way to fix your bug is to continue looking backwards from the call to the method `glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao)`. Follow the program's flow and look for dangerous memory accesses, that's what typically causes overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the syntax sourcefile:line for breakpoint. Like in main.cpp:72. So the command will be like break main.cpp:72

Comment: I tried this and I get "No source file named example1.cpp". I tried relative and absolute paths, same thing. Why wouldn't it be seeing the file?